# Reactive extensions (rx) use only ONE background thread

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm using rx extensions for a simple implementation and it works fine.
I'm using the threadpool scheduler. This works also fine but i want to have only one background thread! The idea ist that i have one ui thread that involes the subject and everything gets fired in one and the same background thread. If there are two request they should be serialized. Is this possible?
Thank you in advance
Laurin

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question? Could you show us a sample of how your code looks like? Why exactly do you need to serialize the execution?

Comment: This is because i am working with a object context behind and it is not threadsafe :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your scheduler to the [`EventLoopScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). It will only have a single thread executing at a time.

You have to create the scheduler for yourself:

```
var loop = new EventLoopScheduler();
```